# How to calculate the speeds two objects need to move at in order to reach different destinations at the same time

Tags: kinematics, speed, distance

For example: On a graph there are two points. Each point has a different destination. The distance between Point A and its destination is 50, and the distance between Point B is 100. The points will begin moving at the same time at a constant speed until they both reach their destination. What speed does each point need to move in order to reach their destination at the same time as the other point if given a time, like 5 seconds.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, if one object travels twice the distance as another in the same amount of time, then first one is moving with twice the speed as the other.

You could show this mathematically by using the equations $$x_1=x_{01}+v_1t\\ x_2=x_{02}+v_2t$$ where $x_{01}$, $x_{02}$ are the initial positions of each object and $v_1$, $v_2$ are their respective speeds and $t$ is the time it takes both objects to reach their destinations.

Since they both start at the same position, then $x_{01}=x_{02}$ and so $$50=v_1t\\ 100=v_2t$$ since one travels a distance $50$ and the other $100$. Solving both these equations by dividing one into the other will give $$\frac{100}{50}=\frac{v_2 t}{v_1 t}$$ so that cancelling the $t$'s will give $$v_2=2v_1$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I realized I forgot to include a part to the problem. I need to move the points to the same place at the same time using a specified time. So for example, if I need them to move to the destinations in 5 seconds, how would I find the speeds required to do this?

Comment: It makes no difference what the specified time is. If the time is the same for both you will get the answer above. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to implement this into a function for an application I'm working on.

Comment: Good work. Cheers.